# How can I find and scrape by Class using WatiN?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, watin, scrape

I am using WatiN and trying to scrape an image URL from a weblink, based on the fields class. Viewing the sites code the images info displays as this:

```
//images code
<div class="doc-banner-icon">
    <img src="https://website.com/image.jpg">
</div>

//text code
<div id="doc-original-text">
    Once upon a time, in a land far far away...
</div>
```

What I want to do is use a WatiN call to find that `img` link. I thought I could use something like the `Find.ByClass()` call to find specifically that area of the code, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the line of text contained within that class. When I use the `Find.ById()` on a different field and sent to string it pulls the text content of that area. Below is what I am trying.

```
using (myIE)
{
    //loads the website
    myIE.GoTo(txtbxWeblink.Text);            

    string infoText = myIE.Div(Find.ByClass("doc-banner-icon")).ToString();

    //This will successfully return the text fields text.
    string imageText = myIE.Div(Find.ById("doc-original-text")).ToString();
}
```

EDIT - It appears that I may need to use a different call on `myIE`, there is also `myIE.Image`, `myIE.Link` etc, I don't know much about this all still so not sure if `Div` is the right call here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
string infoText = myIE.Div(Find.ByClass("doc-banner-icon")).Images.First().Src;
string imageText = myIE.Div(Find.ById("doc-original-text")).Text;
```

Comment: Boom, thank you kindly sir. That worked perfect. Even returned only the url! Perfect.